# ImageView not refreshing correctly in asynctask

Tags: android, bitmap, android-asynctask, imageview

I have the following class modified from the android developer website to load an image into an `imageview`. The `onPostExecute` method is entered, but my `imageview` is not refreshing correctly. I have tried using `imageView.refreshDrawableState`, `requestFocus`, `requestLayout` but all did not work at all.

At first, the `imageview` displays some random colours or displayed nothing. The `imageview` only displayed correctly when I tried to pull down the notification bar. I am pretty sure that the image is loaded because the memory stays the same but just does not get displayed/refreshed correctly.

I call the `async task` in the `public void onWindowFocusChanged()` method.

Can anyone point what am I doing wrongly?

```
ImageView imageView; //set in onCreate method

private class ImageViewAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap>
{
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewWeakReference;
    Activity activity;

    public ImageViewAsyncTask(Activity activity)
    {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.imageViewWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(imageView);
    }

    public int calculateInSampleSize(Options options)
    {
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;
        int reqWidth = imageView.getWidth();
        int reqHeight = imageView.getHeight();

        if (width > reqWidth || height > reqHeight)
        {
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;
            final int halfHeight = height / 2;

            while ((halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth && (halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight)
            {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

    public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Activity activity)
    {
        byte[] decodedImage = Base64.decode(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.cat), 0);
        final Options options = new Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        decodeByteArray(decodedImage, 0, decodedImage.length, options);
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options);
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return decodeByteArray(decodedImage, 0, decodedImage.length, options);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params)
    {
        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        return decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(activity);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        if (imageViewWeakReference != null && bitmap != null)
        {
            final ImageView imageView = imageViewWeakReference.get();
            if (imageView != null)
            {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the imageView variable coming from in the constructor? Typo?

Comment: And when you don't put it in onWindowFocusChanged? The window focus changes when you tap the notification bar, then it is called...so that makes sense.

Comment: the imageView is coming in from the global variable. It is initialized before this method is called. And I'm putting it in the onWindowFocusChanged method because I resize the imageView according to screen size before sampling the image. When I first load, it does go into the postExecute method, just that I do not know why the update is not happening

Comment: Have you tried calling `invalidate()` on the imageView after setting the bitmap?

Comment: Yes, I have tried calling imageView.invalidate(), imageView.refreshDrawableState()